# Responsive jQuery not executing

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I've built a WordPress theme. I need some of the jQuery to be 'responsive', and only execute when the browser window is 600px and up.

My code is as below. It all works if I place the mouseenter actions outside of the $window.resize function. However, trying to use the windows size breaks only the hover portion of the code. I can't figure out why this breaks it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    //Drop menus animate on click
    $("#store_menu .menu-item-has-children").click(function() {
        $("ul", this).slideToggle();       
    });



    //Drop menus animate on hover but only if window is over 600px
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 599){   

            $("#store_menu .menu-item-has-children").mouseenter(function() {
                $("ul", this).slideDown(300);
            });

            $("#store_menu .menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
                $("ul", this).fadeOut();       
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it working for resizing up and not resizing down?

It seems you are not clearing `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on an `else` statement here.
Try adding:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     //Drop menus animate on click
     $("#store_menu .menu-item-has-children").click(function() {
         $("ul", this).slideToggle();       
     });

     function checkSize()
     {
         $("#store_menu .menu-item-has-children").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');

         if ($(window).width() > 599){   

             $("#store_menu .menu-item-has-children").mouseenter(function() {
                 $("ul", this).slideDown(300);
             });

             $("#store_menu .menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
                 $("ul", this).fadeOut();       
             });
         }
     }

     //Drop menus animate on hover but only if window is over 600px
     $(window).resize(function(){
         checkSize();
     });

     //check size on load also
     checkSize();

 });
```

Try changing the `$(window).width()` to `$(document).width()` to make the response more accurate.

Also, keep in mind with this information at [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/resize/):

> Code in a resize handler should never rely on the number of times the handler is called. Depending on implementation, resize events can be sent continuously as the resizing is in progress (the typical behavior in Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers such as Safari and Chrome), or only once at the end of the resize operation (the typical behavior in some other browsers such as Opera).

Comment: Hi. Won't this just execute the code once, when the page loads? I want it to respond to window resizing.

Comment: No, you are "adding" a function to windows resize on the page load. Actually, it won't be called unless you resize your windows after the page loads. Let me change that to a better approach, which is, call at page load AND on every resize.

Comment: @mike_freegan try it now. Please try setting a jsfiddle so I can see the effect if it doesn't work.

Comment: That works, but only on resize. On initial page load, only the click function works, even if the page is over 599px wide. If I change the window size, then the hover effects kick in.

Comment: @mike_freegan Oh god... I misspelled the function name on document load part. It should be `checkSize();` and not `checkResize();`. My bad :P

Comment: That works better, but the hover effect isn't removed when the window drops below 600px.

Comment: I changed the `else` part to `unbind`.

Comment: @mike_freegan I did one last change. If the user keeps resizing the document very often, you would get a LOT of new functions hanged on every resize. Now the code is improved! Glad I helped you!